# Biber 2.11: Data file ... cannot be read in encoding UTF-8 ... ill-formed UTF-8 octet sequence ... at ... Slurper.pm line 63

Tags: biblatex, biber

I have just changed computers, and running Biber 2.11 now produces this error:

```
Utils.pm:209> ERROR - Data file ... cannot be read in encoding 'UTF-8': 
Can't decode ill-formed UTF-8 octet sequence <96> at C:\ ... Slurper.pm line 63
```

My .bib file is huge, having accumulated over years.  Thus, I suspect that there's something malformed in it.  **Is there any rapid way to trouble-shoot it?**

The new machine runs Win 10, Biber 2.11, XeLaTeX 2018.10.31, LaTeX2e 2018-04-01 and TeXLive 2018.  The old machine ran Win 7 and slightly earlier versions of all of the above.

A MWE of the driver .tex file:

```
\documentclass{article} % also with beamer

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % problem arises whether or not include this
\usepackage[backend=biber,bibencoding=utf8]{biblatex} %  problem arises whether or not include this
\addbibresource{bib-mwe.bib}

\begin{document}

cite reference \cite{mal-rwws}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Thanks!

Comment: save a copy of the bib file (just in case:-), then load it into a text editor and re-save it as utf-8 encoding.

Comment: Unfortunately, the underlying library that Biber uses does not provide a line number for the error, see also https://github.com/plk/biber/issues/226. Copy-and-paste or normal recoding might be an option, but depending on how permissive your editor is that might not be enough. You may want to have a look at https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/6516 and similar things on the web. Of course it could be possible that your complete `.bib` file is consistently in an encoding different from UTF-8, then recoding will probably be a good idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As explained in https://github.com/plk/biber/issues/226 the underlying library that Biber uses to read `.bib` files does not provide a line number for the error. So Biber can't tell you the place of the error.

*Usually* the problem is simply that the entire file does not have the guessed/declared encoding. Note that the *entire* file content matters, so even the comments could be an issue.

For the MWE the `.bib` file must be encoded in UTF-8 (or a compatible encoding like US-ASCII). Even without the explicit `bibencoding=utf8`, `biblatex` would guess from the `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` that you are using UTF-8, and if your LaTeX is newer than 2018-04-01, UTF-8 would even be assumed without `inputenc` since it is the standard now.

If a `.bib` file acts up, you should go through the following steps.

1. Determine which encoding it *should* have (usually UTF-8 is a good idea, but if you have declared a different encoding in your `.tex` file, `biblatex` will normally assume that your `.bib` file uses the same encoding, of course that can be overridden with `bibencoding`).
2. Find out which encoding your `.bib` file *actually* has.
3. If the encodings don't match, you need to recode your `.bib` file or tell `biblatex` to try a different encoding.

It may work to just copy and paste the contents of your `.bib` file to a new file that is explicitly set up as UTF-8.

Comment: Is not working. At least when I compile file in repository with `GitHub actions`. I still get the same error

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem. Instead of using a text editor, I opened the .bib file in jabref. You can change the library encoding using 'Library Properties' from the 'File' menu. Then save the library. This also changed the encoding specification on the first line of the .bib file, which I would otherwise have had to change manually (when I would have used the text editor).

Comment: I had a couple of "non-ISO" characters causing the same error. Fixed with JabRef, `Quality`-->`Check Integrity`... finding in one reference _non-ASCII encoded character found_. Click on the reference. Quick look and fixed deleting it.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the helpful comments.

Following [David](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/1090/david-carlisle)'s, the problem is solved by:

1. open the `.bib` file in a text editor (e.g., Notepad)
2. set the encoding in WinEdt (my LaTeX editor) to UTF-8 by clicking on the menu bar at the bottom (originally set to ANSI)
3. create a blank document in WinEdt
4. paste the contents of the original `.bib` file from Notepad into WinEdt
5. save the new WinEdt document as a `.bib` file
6. compile using the new `.bib` file