# Biber: accented character in bib file, Can't decode ill-formed UTF-8 octet sequence

Tags: biblatex, biber, unicode

I'm using MikTeX 2.9 on Windows, `biblatex` v3.12 and `biber` 2.12. The following MWE gives the error

> Data file 'bibliography.bib' cannot be read in encoding 'utf8': Can't decode ill-formed UTF-8 octet sequence  at [...]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[backend=biber,bibencoding=utf8]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}

\begin{document}
See \cite{bar}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

**bibliography.bib**:

```
@book{bar,
   title = {Fóo},
   author = {Bar},
   year = {2018},
   }
```

I'm unable to use accented characters in my `.bib` files.

Comment: Does this help? https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/459821/105447

Comment: Double check that your `.bib` file is really encoded in UTF-8. Open it with a different editor and check the encoding. Sometimes editors only pretend to have changed the encoding, but have not actually re-coded existing file contents.

Comment: Impressive. I opened my `.bib` file in emacs and set `set-buffer-file-coding-system` to `utf-8`. The `Foo` became `FÃ³o` so the bibfile is unreadable, but the result is fine! :o

Comment: @barto Can we mark this as a duplicate in this case?

Comment: @gusbrs Yes, ok.