# Bibliography isn't displayed?

Tags: biblatex

Hi i am new too latex environment. i configure the texstdio bibtex to biber. But My bibliography isn't displaying. It shows warning about empty bibliography and undefined references.

**My main.tex file is**

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage{biblatex}

\addbibresource{lol.bib}

\begin{document}

 Bibliography \cite{lol}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

**My lol.bib file is**

```
@article{lol,
author        = {B. B. CHAUDHURI* and U. PAL},
title         = {A COMPLETE PRINTED BANG¸A OCR SYSTEM},
journaltitle  = {Pattern Recognition Society},
year          = {1998},
volume        = {31},
number        = {5},
pages         = {531-549},
doi           = {10.1016/S0031-3203(97)00078-2}
}
```

**Output is**

Bibliography [lol].

**error is showing.**

[image]

i am stuck for 3 hour. what should i do??

Comment: Double-check your configuration with https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864. Make sure that you are actually calling Biber (in the usual LaTeX, Biber, LaTeX, LaTeX cycle), depending on your settings you have to press an extra button for that (in the tools menu). If you are running Biber, Biber should produce log messages in the `.blg` file. Open that file and paste its contents here (on Windows it might be classified as a 'performance monitor file', but it is really just a text file). See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/286706/35864

Comment: content of .blg file
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/VvhR5gtfBT/

Comment: The message `ERROR - Data file 'lol.bib' cannot be read in encoding 'ascii': ascii "\xC2" does not map to Unicode at` is quite clear about the issue: Your file is not encoded in ASCII, but Biber expects it to be in ASCII. Does https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/402714/35864 help? (Also related, but with UTF-8: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/459821/35864)

Comment: Did you manage to resolve the issue? If so, may I ask how?

Comment: yep 
\usepackage[backend=biber, bibencoding=utf8, style=ieee]{biblatex}
"bibencoding=utf8" solved the issue thanks :)